# Display all tags using acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm looking to just dump a list of tags that have been used on my Posts model.

Is there a way to do this with Acts_as_taggable_on?

Thanks

Comment: How would I display that in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list (with counts) you can do `Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)` which will return an array of objects that look like this:

```
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "joking", taggings_count: 1>,
    #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "clowning", taggings_count: 2>,
    #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "boxing", taggings_count: 1>]
```

which you can then `collect` to get the names if you just want that

Comment: When trying to display <%= @posts.tag_counts_on(:tags) %> just throws #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f0905687468> back at me?

Comment: You need to iterate through it and get the name. `@posts.tag_counts_on(:tags).each do |tag| puts tag.name end` etc etc